# ADO.NET: Safe to specify -1 for SqlParameter.Size for all VarChar parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

We have an existing body of C# code that calls parameterized ad-hoc SQL Server queries in many places. We never specify SqlParameter.Size, and it's documented that in this case, the SqlParameter class infers the size from the parameter value. We just recently became aware of the SQL Server plan cache pollution issues this creates, where a separate plan is cached for each distinct combination of parameter sizes.

Luckily, whenever we create a SqlParameter, we do so via a single utility method, so we have the opportunity to add a few lines to that method and make this problem go away. We are thinking about adding the following:

```
if((sqlDbType == SqlDbType.VarChar) || (sqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar))
    m_sqlParam.Size = -1;
```

In other words, every time we pass a varchar parameter, pass it as a varchar(max). Based on some quick testing, this works fine, and we can see (via SQL Profiler and sys.dm_exec_cached_plans) that there is now a single plan in the cache for each ad-hoc query, and the type of the string parameter(s) is now varchar(max).

This seems like such an easy solution that there must be some hidden, performance-destroying downside. Is anyone aware of one?

(Please note that we only need to support SQL Server 2008 and later.)

### Update (Jan. 16)

**Yes, there is a hidden, performance-destroying downside!**

Many thanks to Martin Smith, whose answer (see below) pointed me to the right way to analyze this. I tested with our application's Users table, which has an Email column defined as nvarchar(100), and has a non-clustered index (IX_Users_Email) on the Email column. I modified Martin's example query as follows:

```
declare @a nvarchar(max) = cast('a' as nvarchar(max))
--declare @a nvarchar(100) = cast('a' as nvarchar(100))
--declare @a nvarchar(4000) = cast('a' as nvarchar(4000))

select Email from Users where Email = @a
```

Depending which of the "declare" statements I un-comment, I get a VERY different query plan. The nvarchar(100) and nvarchar(4000) versions both give me an index **seek** on IX_Users_Email -- in fact, any length I specify gives me the same plan. The nvarchar(max) version, on the other hand, gives me an index **scan** on IX_Users_Email, followed by a Filter operator to apply the predicate.

That's enough for me -- if there is any possibility of getting a scan rather than a seek, then this "cure" is worse than the disease.

**New Proposal**

I noticed that every time SQL Server parameterizes a query with a varchar parameter, the cached plan simply uses varchar(8000) (or nvarchar(4000)) for the parameter. I figure if it's good enough for SQL Server, it's good enough for me! Replacing the C# code in my original question (above) with:

```
if(sqlDbType == SqlDbType.VarChar)
    m_sqlParam.Size = 8000;
else if(sqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    m_sqlParam.Size = 4000;
```

This seems to solve the plan cache pollution problem without the same impact on the query plans as using a Size of -1. However, I have not done a lot of testing with this, and I am very interested to hear anyone's input on this revised approach.

### Update (Sep. 24)

We had to modify the prior version (New Proposal, above) to handle the case where the parameter value is longer than the maximum. At that point, you have no choice but to make it a varchar(max):

```
if((sqlDbType == SqlDbType.VarChar) || (sqlDbType == SqlDbType.NVarChar))
{
    m_sqlParam.Size = (sqlDbType == SqlDbType.VarChar) ? 8000 : 4000;

    if((value != null) && !(value is DBNull) && (value.ToString().Length > m_sqlParam.Size))
        m_sqlParam.Size = -1;
}
```

We've been using this version for about six months with no problems.

Comment: We are creatures that love to create complexity for some reason. Your solution is sound. This would be no different than having a table with a legitimate `VARCHAR(MAX)` field in it. You can safely believe that Microsoft has thoroughly tested that data type.

Comment: I have read about this issue but thought it was solved for Linq2Sql and Entity Framework a long time ago. I had not considered ad-hoc sql. Or rather, this seems to me like something that Sql Server should handle better. Very good question and you have my upvote. Curious to find out more about this.

Comment: Could it be so simple that sys.dm_exec_cached_plans only reports what is coming in, and that there is optimization further down the food chain inside Sql Server? Seems like a obvious optimization to me and I have a hard time believing that the brains behind Sybase all through all versions of Sql Server haven't thought about this.

Comment: So a question for you Rand. Have you measured performance with and without this Size = -1? If it mattered it surely would be in every textbook there is about using Sql Server.

Comment: I wonder how big performance impact is for not setting size matching datatype ?

We were thinking about similar approach, but we don't have single utility to create `SqlParameter`. We are looking for some global interceptor, and we have second approach to create Roslyn Analyzer that will rise an error during compilation, so Developer will be forced to set size

Comment: @MichaelViktorStarberg With different parameter sizes there will be different query plans. This makes DMV's needlessly messy, which in turn makes it difficult to aggregate queries for performance analysis, and entirely *breaks* something like Query Store for forcing a plan.

Comment: As far as a downside, largest issue is I know of converting a varchar(1..8000) to varchar(max) and vice-versa due to implicit conversions at the database. There is much less 'cost' between size changes in varchar(1..8000) to other sizes within such, and it is *already done* with the pick-the-size. SQL server doesn't consider varchar sizes for plan selection. Honestly don't know why it's so hard to find questions about such..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not ideal in that it is best to specify a parameter that matches the datatype of the column(s) involved.

You would need to check your query plans to see if they still look reasonable.

Trying the following test

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
X VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
)


DECLARE @A VARCHAR(MAX) = CAST('A' AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT *
FROM #T 
WHERE X = @A
```

Gives a plan like

[image: Plan]

SQL Server adds a compute scalar to the plan which calls the internal function `GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes` and still manages to perform an index seek ([more details on implicit conversions here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170303101108/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/01/18/dynamic-seeks-and-hidden-implicit-conversions.aspx)).

A counter example where it does matter is shown in the article [Why Doesn’t Partition Elimination Work?](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422160838/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/12/why-doesn-t-partition-elimination-work.aspx). The behaviour described in that article also applies for a `varchar(max)` parameter against a table partitioned on a `varchar(n)` column.